# How do you configure ASP.NET Core 7 to use JWT Token with the default Identity login form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

I am trying to add an jwt bearer token login to the api section of the site only http://localhost/api and make the rest accessible through the identity login form. I am using ASP.NET Core 7.

I have manage to get the JWT Bearer token working using;

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(k =>
{
    k.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    k.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(p =>
{
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWTToken:key"]);
    p.SaveToken = true;
    p.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWKToekn:key"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWKToekn:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
    };
});
```

Although when I pass the generated token it still returns a 401. Currently it won't let me login using the default Identity form when I add the JWTBearer. It is possible to get it to work on the http://localhost/api

Comment: 1. You have typos in configuration section key for `ValidIssuer` and `ValidAudience`. You have `JWKToekn`, while I believe you meant `JWTToken`. 2. Don't use token key as token issuer. Issuer, audience and other token properties are public, so you don't want to expose your secret key. Use token key only for signing the token. 3. Please share the application builder configuration, that is calls that are after service registration i.e. `app.UseEndpoints()` or `app.UseRouting()`.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you generate the JWT token inside Identity form?

Comment: I managed to solve this. Although I wanted to be able to login using multiple authentication schemes I just ended specifying two schemes and just add ``[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`` to the controller whenever I wanted to use the jwt token.

Comment: Check out this article that uses Identity for JWT auth. https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/aspnet-core-api-with-jwt-authentication/

Comment: I want to know how you generate the token and send it to the clinet.